# Activate license on cisco wireless controller

Tags: cisco, access-point, controller

I have a Cisco Model 2504 wireless controller. I currently have 7 access points using the controller. I have purchased a new wireless access point, model AIR-CAP3702I-A-K9.

I purchased a license to add the controller. I added the license using the 'install license' command in CLI using tftp, and was notified the license was installed successfully.

I then restarted the router.

However when I connect the WAP to the controller with an ethernet cable it does not find the controller. The display light blinks alternately green and red.

When I use the `show license all` command, I see the following:

```
License Store: Primary License Storage
StoreIndex:  0  Feature: base                              Version: 1.0
        License Type: Permanent
        License State: Active, Not in Use
        License Count: Non-Counted
        License Priority: Medium
License Store: Primary License Storage
StoreIndex:  1  Feature: base-ap-count                     Version: 1.0
        License Type: Permanent
        License State: Inactive
        License Count: 5 / 0 (Active/In-use)
        License Priority: Medium
License Store: Primary License Storage
StoreIndex:  2  Feature: base-ap-count                     Version: 1.0
        License Type: Permanent
        License State: Active, In Use
        License Count: 7 /7 (Active/In-use)
        License Priority: Medium
License Store: Evaluation License Storage
StoreIndex:  0  Feature: base-ap-count                     Version: 1.0
        License Type: Evaluation
        License State: Inactive
            Evaluation total period: 12 weeks  6 days 
            Evaluation period left: 12 weeks  6 days 
        License Count: 75 / 0 (Active/In-use)
        License Priority: None
```

I know that the second to last is the licenses I was already using, and the last is the evaluation licenses. I believe the license I installed is the second one, which says `license count: 5/0 (Active/In-use)`.

How do I activate this license? How do I make the wireless access point connect to the controller?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/wireless/controller/7.4/configuration/guides/system_management/config_system_management_chapter_011.html#ID609  ??

Comment: @RonTrunk thank you that is a good resource. I will see if the answer to my question is in there.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what is going on. I had purchased and adder license, but if you just install it it only installs as a base-ap-license, which isn't what you want. I needed to create a new base-ap-license at Cisco, according to the directions here:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/controller/7-5/configuration-guide/b_cg75/b_cg75_chapter_011.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Sounds less like a licensing issue and more like a discovery of the WLC issue. Have you looked at the AP Join stats on the WLC or console output of the AP itself? I would want to see where in the discovery/registration process the AP is failing.

Comment: I did `debug capwap events enable` and among the list of events I saw this: `*spamApTask2: Sep 03 16:25:49.603: 58:97:bd:86:4e:8c Refusing Discovery Request from AP 58:97:bd:86:4e:8c - limit  for maximum APs supported 7 reached`. So it does seem like a license issue.

Comment: Agreed. Can you screenshot the licensing page at Management -> Software Activation -> Licenses?